# YAML - groovy - env var can't be an integer?

Tags: grails

Project is in Groovy/Grails/Gradle/Camel Routes

This seems pretty reasonable:

```
server:
    port: ${PORT}
```

But I get :

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${PORT}"
    at org.grails.config.CodeGenConfig.convertToType(CodeGenConfig.groovy:191)
    at org.grails.config.CodeGenConfig.getProperty(CodeGenConfig.groovy:264)
    at grails.config.ConfigMap$getProperty.call(Unknown Source)
    at run-app.run(run-app.groovy:31)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.commands.script.GroovyScriptCommand.handle(GroovyScriptCommand.groovy:152)
    at org.grails.cli.profile.AbstractProfile.handleCommand(AbstractProfile.groovy:452)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.handleCommand(GrailsCli.groovy:373)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli$_handleCommandWithCancellationSupport_closure6.doCall(GrailsCli.groovy:464)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli$_handleCommandWithCancellationSupport_closure6.call(GrailsCli.groovy)
```

String env vars do not have an issue and work just fine.
I cannot find any syntax to make cast to an int when I search.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's actual value of `$PORT`? Are you sure you can simply inject an envvar in your yml config? The error appears to be that the string "${PORT}" is not an integer, which is true.

Comment: I am using intellij, and I set PORT to 8081 in the Environment Variables when I edit the run config under Grails.  Yes I can inject other vars as long as they are strings using ${ } pattern.... is there a better pattern?

Comment: This is valid YAML (i.e. you **can** have a unquoted string scalar `${PORT}` without any problem), therefore removed the inappropriate tag.

Comment: Switched to a groovy script.

Answer (score 1):

In a Grails/Spring Boot app, if the configuration is short hand as below:

```
server:
    port: ${PORT}
```

then the app expects `--PORT=8090` (for example) to be provided as a System arg / environment property upon application startup. Make sure that environment variable is provided.

To make the environment variable value available in `application.yml` we would also need below task configuration in Grails apps:

```
bootRun {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

With plain vanilla Spring Boot Maven apps above is not required.

Also, to avoid any kind of exception we can also provide a default value for port if feasible like below:

```
server:
    port: ${PORT:8085}
```

Comment: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${PORT:8443}"  I get the same error. It won't read it in as something it has to interpret, which is odd because I have plenty of other ones set in the file, using the exact same pattern.  But they are all string values.  Also adding the  `bootRun {
    systemProperties = System.properties }` doesn't change anything